# How to create a trigger in php myadmin

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to use a trigger in phpmyadmin with join and if...else conditions?

Here is my trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `visit`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `visit` 
AFTER INSERT ON `daily_call_reports` 
FOR EACH ROW
    Update dealers d 
    JOIN daily_call_reports dcr
              ON d.dealer_id = dcr.client_id

         IF d.visit  IS NULL THEN 
                SET d.visit  = 1

          else  
                SET d.visit  = visit+1

          WHERE  dcr.client_id = NEW.client_id
```

But when I click "go" button, it shows this error:

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right  syntax to use near 'IF d.visit IS NULL THEN SET d.visit = 1 
els' at line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (for syntax)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name after insert ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  INSERT  INTO `table2` (column1,column2) VALUES (NEW.column1,NEW.cllumn2);

END $$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Delimiter in trigger because by default delimiter i.e semicolon (;) not works.

Refer this link to understand delimiter:

[why to use Delimiter?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

The update statement is not correct since you can not have if-else within the update command the way you are trying. You may change the update part as

```
update dealers d 
join daily_call_reports dcr on d.dealer_id = dcr.client_id
set d.visit  = 
case when d.visit  IS NULL then 1 else visit+1 end
where dcr.client_id = NEW.client_id
```